# BIM360 API Data Export - Attribute to find Issues created from Checklists

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a query with API data export from BIM360. I have exported Issues and checklists data separately using the Get connectors for Checklists  and Issues.

I cannot find the link to identify Issues that are created from checklists.

Could you please advise the attribute which provides this information in JSON output of these connectors?

Comment: so, you extracted all checklist and issue data by Data Connector, and now you wanted to know which issue comes from (associates with) the checklist? Unfortunately, Data Connector does not tell such attributes. Ideally, such information could be available with Relationship API, but Checklist of BIM360 does not expose the support with that. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim-360acc-relationships-api

Comment: in addition, by checklist API, there is one attribute issueId for Instance, but this attribute is always null with my test. I have logged this problem with engineer team at the internal ticket: SCCOM-7651 IssueIds are always null with GET Checklist Instance

Comment: Hi  Xiaodong Liang, Thanks for your quick response and for raising the internal ticket to address the null values for IssuesIDs with GET checklist instances; This may resolve the issue if the relevant IssueIDs are pulled with each checklists.